# Spring Boot Data JPA detect database disconnection

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration flow that retrieves data from a data stream, process it and them persists the result in a relational database. The flow is working just fine. I want to stop/resume the flow in response to the database availability, stop it when the database disconnects for any reason and resume it when it is reconnected. How can I achieve this? Is there a standard DatasourceConnected/DatasourceDisconnected Spring event?

For the source data stream there is a ConnectionListener I can implement to do this, I don't know how to do it for the output.

Answer (score 0):

While there isn't a specific DatasourceConnected or DatasourceDisconnected event provided by Spring, you can create your own custom events and listeners to handle the database availability changes.you can follow this steps:
Create custom events: Define your own custom events to represent the database connection status changes. For example, you can create a DatabaseConnectedEvent and a DatabaseDisconnectedEvent. These events will be triggered when the database connection is established or lost.
Implement the event listeners: Implement event listeners that will respond to these custom events. You can create a listener for the DatabaseConnectedEvent that triggers the resumption of the integration flow, and another listener for the DatabaseDisconnectedEvent that stops the flow.
Publish the events: Use appropriate mechanisms to publish the custom events based on the database connection status. For example, you can have a separate component responsible for monitoring the database connection, and when a change is detected, it can publish the corresponding event.
For the source data stream, as you mentioned, you can implement a ConnectionListener to detect the connection status changes and publish the custom events accordingly.

Comment: I understand what are suggesting regarding the custom events, my follow up would be how to detect the connection status changes. Send an operation to the database (a simple query for instance) and catch exceptions? Same for reconnection, how I'd go about detecting it in a Spring data context? Does HikariCP play a part in all this?

Comment: HikariCP provides a feature called "connection health check" that allows you to monitor the status of the database connection. By default, HikariCP uses a simple query (SELECT 1) to validate the connection health. If the query fails, it indicates a connection issue.

Comment: and when an operation, such as a query, is executed using Spring Data and HikariCP, any exceptions related to the connection status, like connection failure or timeout, are typically thrown as a DataAccessException or a more specific subclass such as CannotGetJdbcConnectionException. You can catch these exceptions and handle them appropriately to respond to connection status changes.